# Popup in Deck.gl when using Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, deck.gl, js-routes

I'm using `deck.gl` and `routes` in my JS app and am having some trouble with popups.
If I use `deck.gl` as a standalone (without `routes`) then I can display popups, but using *exactly the same code* in a `routes` framework fails. The console shows that the `_renderTooltip` function is being called, but nothing is shown. Can anyone tell me why?

This is my tooltip renderer:

```
  _renderTooltip()
  {
    const {x, y, object} = this.state;
    if (object)
    {
        return (
            object && (
            <div className="tooltip" style={{top: y, left: x}}>
            <div><b>THIS</b></div>
            </div>
            )
            );
        }
    }
```

Which is called via:

```
new GeoJsonLayer({id: 'geojson_positions', data: data, pickable: true, onHover: this._onHover})
```

Using:

```
  _onHover({x, y, object}) {
    this.setState({x, y, object: object});
  }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @giuliov, no I didn't, unfortunately.